# Codeigniter 2.1 and .htaccess - rewrite url

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite this url:

> domain.com/mali_oglasi/index/1(any number)

to:

> domain.com/mali_oglasi

In my .htaccess file I have this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only thing you want is to map your controller/method differently than the default behaviour, you can use the `route.php` config file. See the official documentation here : http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

In your case you'll have something like this :

```
$route['mali_oglasi/index/(:num)'] = 'mali_oglasi';
```

Later in your controller you can still get the original digit by using :

```
$this->uri->rsegment(3);
```

instead of :

```
$this->uri->segment(3);
```

(see official documentation here : http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html )

**EDIT:**

In fact, if you just wish to get rid of the "index" segment when you need to add parameter, you may want to do the inverse of my first answer :

```
$route['mali_oglasi/(:num)'] = 'mali_oglasi/index/$1';
```

With that line, every request in the form of "www.yourdomain.com/mali_oglasi/1" will be interpreted by codeigniter as if it were "www.yourdomain.com/mali_oglasi/index/1". Meaning the method "index" of the controller "mali_oglasi" will be used to handle your request.

If you need to retrieve the digit, you want to use :

```
$this->uri->segment(3);
```

So if your client should ever go to the url "www.yourdomain.com/mali_oglasi/index/1" directly, you will still retrieve the good uri segment. ( `$this->uri->segment(n);` give you the n-th segment after `route.php` rewrite the uri, and `$this->uri->rsegment(n)` give you the n'th segment before the uri is rewritten. )

Comment: Then what do you need exactly ? That the display address in the browser becomes domain.com/mali_oglasi ? If so you'll need to do a redirection. Changing the .htaccess won't do anything.

Comment: That is the idea - to display url in short form. I tried to do this with $route (your way and a few other ways) but it doesn't change the way url is displayed.

Comment: Do you need to do this for all the url of your site, or just for the mali_oglasi controller and the index method ? In the first case, you're better to forget it

Comment: Do you need to do this for all the url of your site, or just for the mali_oglasi controller and the index method ?
In the first case, you're better to forget it, you'll have to change the way codeigniter works and to use lot's of complex mecanism to keep track of what page your user ask.
I'll edit my answer for the second case.
(sorry wasn't able to edit my previous comment and hit the enter key by accident)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to redirect the user to the new URL :

in your controller `mali_oglasi` >> in the function `index`

put the below line

```
redirect('mali_oglasi');
```

e.g.

class mali_oglasi extends CI_Controller{

```
function Index($id){
    // Note : make sure you have loaded the url helper
    redirect('mali_oglasi');
}
```

}

**Note:** don't forget to load the `url helper`

**Note:**  Set the `$config['index_page'] = '';` instead of `index` in `application/config/config.php`